# Universal digraph

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

The Rado graph is universal since it contains an isomorphic copy of every countable graph (infinitely often). The Rado graph can be explicitely [constructed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Construction_via_binary_numbers) and an isomorphic copy of any countable graph can be effectively [computed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rado_graph#Finding_isomorphic_subgraphs).

> Is there also a universal **directed** graph,
>   especially one with an explicit
>   construction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use the same construction as the Rado graph, but replace the base 2 by base 4.  The vertices are in one-to-one correspondence with the natural numbers, with edges obeying the following rule.

For any two vertices $x,y$ with $x<y$:

1. If the $x$th bit of the base-4 expansion of $y$ is a $0$, then there are no edges between $x$ and $y$.
2. If the $x$th bit of the base-4 expansion of $y$ is a $1$, then there is a directed edge from $x$ to $y$.
3. If the $x$th bit of the base-4 expansion of $y$ is a $2$, then there is a directed edge from $y$ to $x$.
4. If the $x$th bit of the base-4 expansion of $y$ is a $3$, then there are directed edges in both directions between $x$ and $y$.

This has very similar properties to the Rado graph, and roughly the same algorithm works for finding induced subgraphs of a given isomorphism type.

Incidentally, the idea here is presumably the same as the construction of 4-edge-colored Rado graph $G_4$ mentioned in "related concepts" section of the same Wikipedia article.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have a reference where I can learn a little bit more about the directed Rado graph?

Comment: @Hans: I would recommend looking up references on the 4-edge-colored Rado graph, e.g. the reference to Truss (1985) mentioned in the article.  A directed graph really isn't very different from the type of 4-edge-colored graph they are considering.